# Unable To Load image while share image using instagram android?

Tags: android, share, instagram

I am try to share image from sdcard manually but it will gives error unable
   to load image

```
 String uri="file:///storage/emulated/0/Ingreets/20161227165518.jpeg"

 Uri u = Uri.parse (uri);
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 shareIntent.setType ("image/*");
 shareIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);
 shareIntent.setPackage ("com.instagram.android");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to"));
```

Comment: Please provide a **complete** code example. This means that you should give the class and method just as it is in your actual code. I should be able to copy and paste your code and compile it myself. Also, please explain what happens when you run your app. Do you get any errors? If so, provide the full compiler error or stacktrace. If not, what does the app do that is different from what you require?